# How to deny access to the registration page for authorized users? Symfony 5

Tags: security, redirect, symfony5

I want to restrict access for authorized users to the registration page.
But so far all that I have found on this topic is the ability to restrict access to some controller for unregistered users.

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
```

Using this code, a redirect to the authorization page is made if the user is not authorized.
But I need the other way around, I will be very happy if you can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.
In the controller, this can be done like this:

```
if ($this->getUser()) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_home');
}
```